# binomial sum bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$ that is $X \sim \mathrm{bin}(n,p)$.

Does anyone know of a good lower bound (interms of $n$ and $p$) on the probability that $P(X \geq m)$? For $m<n$.

Comment: define *good* lower bound.. $0$ is a lower bound. So it $p^n$. And also $p^n + np(1-p)^{n-1}$. You should be more specific! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i guess i'm looking for the closest 'closed form approximation'?

Comment: There are some tail bounds at the very end of : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Yes but all of them are upper bounds, i'm looking for a lower bound.